# How to change Android Window Manager/Activity Manager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-ndk

I want to learn how to program for the android framework? Where can I make custom changes?
I want to write a simple POC which shows more than 2 activities(dynamic not static) in one window in android (2 running activities running in the same window).
Help me getting the basic understanding of these stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Activities loading like stack model.

So only one activity will be display in one window.

two activities not possible in one window.

you can use service.

Comment: If developing for tablets, you can use multiple fragments.

Comment: That is the actual thing i wanna display 2 activities in one window. I guess i need to customize the window manager or the activity manager accordingly.